# How to add checkbox in header in ui-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid to display permissions . in cellTemplate displaying checkbox and perfoming updation ..like selected checkbox and all checkbox selection.Now i want to add checkbox in header and once its clicked select all below checkbox and deselect all.If only one selected '-' sign has to appear ...
This is code i am trying

```
 angular.forEach($scope.moduleRoles, function (role, key) {
                $scope.mgridOptions.columnDefs.push({name: role, displayName: role, width: 150,headerCellTemplate: "<span> \
        <span  ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" class=\"ngHeaderText\"> \
            {{col.displayName}} \
            '<input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"role.checked\" class=\"chckBox\" ng-click=\"checkAll(role.checked);\">' \
        </span> \
    </span>" , cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="row.entity.roles[\'' + key + '\'].selected" ng-click="grid.appScope.updateModulePerms(row.entity,\'' + key + '\')">'});
            });
```

$scope.moduleRoles contains roles data which coming from server.
I am able to add checkbox in header ..But checkAll function is not working and not able to change  checkbox design.

Where i am wrong.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$scope.optionsGrid = {
    enableSelectAll: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: true
}
```

and then add a callback function handler for the row selection event:

```
$scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
                $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, callbackFunction);
                gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChangedBatch($scope, callbackFunction);
            }
 }
```